# Randomly Merging List

Tags: python, list, indexing, merge

I am trying to get my output randomly generated, e.g.

1. fluffy duck
2. derpy turtle

for the complete list.

```
import random
myVerb2= ["funny","cheesy","cute","fluffy","derpy","nerdy","sad","sleepy","adorable ", "slinky"] 
print (random.choice(myVerb2)) 

myList= ["dog", "cat", "bear", "fish", "monkey", "bird", "turtle", "goose", "zebra", "deer"] 
print (random.choice(myList))
```

Comment: So... what's your question?

Comment: By "for the complete list," do you mean ten lines, each with a random adjective (not verb) and a random noun? If you want the entire list of possible combinations, it's not random.

Comment: That's not specific enough. Might 3 be "sleepy monkey"? Or do you want each item from each `list` to appear exactly once?

Answer (score 1):

To do the whole lists use `random.shuffle` and `zip` to get pairs:

```
random.shuffle(myVerb2)
random.shuffle(myList)


for ind, (v, a) in enumerate(zip(myVerb2,myList),1):
    print("{}. {} {}".format(ind, v,a))
```

Output:

```
1. cheesy goose
2. fluffy cat
3. funny dog
4. sleepy bear
5. cute zebra
6. adorable  bird
7. nerdy monkey
8. sad deer
9. derpy turtle
10. slinky fish
```

If you want to store the pairs assign the output of zip to a variable:

```
paired = zip(myVerb2,myList)

print(list(paired))
```